# Where can I find a Lisp reader in C?

Tags: c, lisp

I have a Lisp reader written in Java that I'm thinking of translating into C.  (Or perhaps C++.)  It's a fairly complete and useful hack, so the main issue is doing the dynamic-storage allocation in a language without garbage collection.  If someone has already thought this through I'd rather borrow their code than figure it out myself.  (C is not my favorite language.)

Of course, having a Lisp reader makes no sense unless you're planning to do something with the things you read, so perhaps I should have phrased the question, Where do I find a simple Lisp core written in C?, but in my experience the hardest unavoidable part of writing a Lisp (somewhat surprisingly) is the reader.  Plus, I don't want to have a garbage collector; I'm anticipating an application where the list structures will be freed more or less by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Gary Knott's [Interpreting Lisp](http://www.civilized.com/getlisp.html) is very nice.
You may also try others, like [Jim Mayfield's](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~mayfield/202/code) Lisp. There are probably lots of little Lisps out there...

You mentioned that you don't like C. Maybe you'd like Haskell -- in which case you could try ["Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours), an interesting tutorial (you get to write a Scheme interpreter in Haskell).

**Update:** I know that a Lisper would hardly feel comfortable using Haskell, but hey, it's much more comfortable than C (at least for me)! Besides that, HAskell has a good FFI, so it should be easy to use the Haskell-made Lisp-reader as a C-compatible library.

**Update 2:** If you want to use XLisp, as suggested by another user, you will probably need src/xlread.c (863 lines) and include/xlisp.h (1379 lines) -- but I could be wrong...

**Update 3:** If you use Gary Knott's Lisp (one single C file with 942 lines), the function signature is int32 sread(void). This would be my choie if I didn't need anything fancy (like read macros) or highly optimized (there is a PDF paper that describes how the code is implemented, so you won't have to find your way in a labyrinth). The documentation for the function is:

```
This procedure scans an input string g using a lexical token scanning
routine, e(), where e() returns
                    1 if the token is '('
                    2 if the token is '''
                    3 if the token is '.'
                    4 if the token is ')'   or a typed pointer d to an
atom or number stored in row ptrv(d) in   the atom or number tables.
Due to the typecode (8 or 9) of d, d is a negative 32-bit integer.  The
token found by e() is stripped from the front of g.

SREAD constructs an S-expression and returns a typed pointer to it as
its result.
```

See that Gary's Lisp is old and you'll need to change it so it compiles. Instead of including linuxenv.h, include:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
```

Also, it does not work in 64-bit machines (the documentation of sread should tell you why...)

**Update 4**: There's also the [Scheme implementations](http://www.bcl.hamilton.ie/~nmh/t3x.org/zzz/) by Nils Holm (there are books describing the internals)

Comment: Thanks; I will look into the Knott thing.

On Haskell: Nothing against Haskell, but if I wanted to do it in a beautiful functional environment, I would just do it in Lisp :)

Answer (score 3):

Lisp500  http://code.google.com/p/lisp5000

ThinLisp   http://www.thinlisp.org

Answer (score 2):

[lispreader](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/lispreader/index.html) is a simple Lisp file parser done in plain C.

If you want C++, you can dig around in the [SuperTux source code](http://supertux.lethargik.org/svn/supertux/trunk/supertux/src/lisp/), it contains a Lisp file parser written in C++.

When you want an actual implementation of Lisp instead of just a parser you could have a look at [Abuse](http://abuse.zoy.org/), which contains a small one as the games scripting language.

Comment: Now, why does that make me think of Greenspun's Tenth Rule?  :)

Answer (score 2):

MIT Professor Rivest published a set of small readers for s-expressions back in 1997 http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/sexp.html as part of his DARPA supported research on public key cryptography. The code only does reading and printing and is well described in a document written in the style of an internet RFC.

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of embeddable Scheme implementations, off the top of my head: [SIOD](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/scheme-repository/imp/siod.html), [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html), [ChickenScheme](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/), [Scheme48](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/s48/)....

Comment: I know I could grab some code out of sources like those, but they're a bit too heavy for what I'm looking for.  A lot of their design is motivated by global factors (especially the GC) that don't apply here.  I want something fairly lightweight --- basic Lisp data structures, something to read them in, and conventions for freeing them.